# Are DbContext-derived classes static?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

If I do this in my model class `VocabModel` (which is derived from DbContext):

```
public VocabModel() : base("DefaultConnection")
{

    if (Membership.GetUser()!=null)
    {
        this.currentuser = UserProfiles.Find((int)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey);
    }

}
```

Will it change the same currentuser member for each user (or session), making my code unusable, or is there a distinct VocabModel for everyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you made `currentuser` a static member, then no.

In fact, DbContexts should never be static, particularly in web applications since they have a state that would get corrupted by multiple users using it simultaneously.